# Minimal polynomial of upper triangular block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials, block-matrices

Let $T$ be a upper triangular block matrix

\begin{bmatrix}
    A     & B \\
    0     & C \\
\end{bmatrix}

I want to show that the minimal polynomials of $A$ and $C$ divide the minimal polynomial of $T$. I know that it is true for the block diagonal matrix, but I don't know how to deal with $B$.

Thank you.

Comment: A polynomial applied to $T$ results in a matrix that has the polynomial applied to $A$ and $C$ in place of $A$ and $C$. If you apply the minimal polynomial of $T$ to $T$, in particular, you get that that polynomial applied to $A$ made it zero. Since the minimal polynomial of $A$ divides all polynomials of which $A$ is a root, if follows that the minimal of $A$ divides the minimal of $T$. Likewise with $C$.

Comment: Thank you. So If I apply $p$ to $T$ I get a block matrix with blocks $p(A),B,p(C),0$? Why is that?

Comment: I didn't make any claim about what appears in place of $B$. For what happens in the place of $A$ and $B$ you only need to check what happens with powers of $T$, sums of upper block triangular, and multiplication by scalar.

Answer (score 2):

If $m$ denotes the minimal polynomial of your matrix and $p,q$ are the minimal polynomials of $A$ and $C$ respectively,  then 
$$
m\left(\begin{bmatrix} A&B\\ 0&C\end{bmatrix}\right)=\begin{bmatrix} m(A)&*\\0&m(C)\end{bmatrix},
$$
so $m(A)=0$ and $m(C)=0$. This implies that $p|m$ and $q|m$.

Comment: Because $\begin{bmatrix}A&B\\0&C\end{bmatrix}^n = \begin{bmatrix}A^n&*\\0&C^n\end{bmatrix}$.